# sed command not replacing ip address via variables

Tags: bash, shell, sed

My development environment setup is such that it requires me to have certain host-name to localIP entry in /etc/host file .( Reason being multiple micro-services and storage i.e Cassandra and Redis bound to host-name )
I have created this simple bash script

```
newIP=`ip a | grep wlp5s0 | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | head -1`
echo $newIP
oldIP=`ping -q -c 1 -t 1 dummy | grep PING | sed -e "s/).*//" | sed -e "s/.*(//"`
echo $oldIP
sed -i 's/$oldIP/$newIP/g' /etc/hosts
```

Althrough this is printing correct ip but the replacement is not happening 
, looks to me as an issue with sed  but not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should changed your sed command in the following way:

```
sed -i "s/$oldIP/$newIP/g" /etc/hosts
```

if you use simple quotes ***" ' "*** your variable will not be replaced by its value!

You can also edit your first regex in the following way:

```
\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b
```

Last but not least, you should take a backup of your `/etc/hosts` file before using sed in in-place mode, to avoid bad surprises.

Hope that it helps!

Comment: Like maybe using `sed -i.bak "s/$oldIP/$newIP/g" /etc/hosts` ??

Comment: Thanks  for the answer ,this works .can you also tell advantage of changing the regex.

Comment: The regex is more compact. 
less writing/less reading for the same behavior  -> gain in productivity, and better for your fingers, eyes . :-)

In term of performances, I don't know if using `\d` is better but the regex string will be smaller (little gain in memory consumption)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation